# How to make AdMob work when developing on a 2.2 device?

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, android-2.2-froyo

There are quite a few questions around this subject but I couldn't quite find a solution.

I'm using eclipse to develop for Android and I want to test on my phone, which is an Android 2.2 HTC desire.

I'm using latest AdMob sdk, deployed by android tool (rev 4), my Sdk is android to latest (sdk tools in rev 16, platform-tools in rev 10, API 7 to 15).

I've read that to use Admob, I must:

- have AndroidManifest.xml with an entry

  ```
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
  ```
- to have the `screenSize|smallestScreenSize` flags supported, I must use `target=android-13` in my `project.properties`. (this can be also done in eclipse by changing project build target)
- to support my old phone (android-2.2 = API-8), I need to add `android:minSdkVersion="8"` in my manifest.xml : this actually allows to run an exported apk on that phone (tested, by compiling apk then deploying using adb), but not to debug on eclipse (eclipse expects to have a device compliant with buildtarget, not minsdk version)
- my computer is fairly old and using the simulator is not really an option (nor is purchasing one for that matter)
- reverting to an older sdk does not seem smart (it's just postponing the issue and is usually a bad choice.

Now that the situation is here, how can I develop in eclipse while using latest AdMob sdk and debug on my 2.2 target ?

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse doesn't pick up the device.  Have you tried installing the app from the command line?  Once your device is plugged in, running `adb devices` can get you your device id, and `adb -s YOUR_DEVICE_ID install path/to/your.apk` should install it on your phone.

Comment: installing the app on command line works, what doesn't work is installing / debugging from eclipse directly. Basically, I just lack the integration with the IDE.

Comment: It's good that the command line route works at least.  It should still work via Eclipse as well - the device normally is an available option  as long as it's at least as high as the minSdkVersion, even if it is lower than the targetSdkVersion.  I'm not quite sure why it doesn't for you.

Comment: I'd be glad to provide traces or additional information if this can help fixing it :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what additional information would help.  The only other tip I have to offer is running `adb kill-server` (and `adb start-server` if for some reason kill-server doesn't restart it automatically).  I have used this command to get Eclipse to start recognizing emulators that were running; maybe it will recognize the device as well if it is already plugged in.

Comment: device is actually recognised, I was just fooled by the red cross : my swiss sense of respect prevented me from clicking :-) (see my answer). Anyway, problem fix, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated to latest ADT (16)

Now, eclipse says:

- choose a device compatible with target Android 3.2
- My device (android 2.2.2) is displayed with a red cross

However, I can double-click this target and eclipse will correctly run on it. I can now debug on my 2.2 device directly from eclipse. As a side note, I might have been fooled by the red cross displayed in eclipse and not "force" to run on device.

*EDIT* : fixed formatting

Comment: I don't like how Eclipse does this.  It is red because the 2.2 device is lower than the targetSdkVersion.  But it is higher than the minSdkVersion, so it is a valid device to run the app on.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Just done 3 things:

1.Created a project targeting SDK Version 2.2, used this code in manifest

```
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

1. Changed target in project.properties file

   ```
   target=android-15
   ```
2. In manifest minSdkVersion remains 8

   ```
   uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
   ```

and job done.

Comment: If I set `target=8` and do the change you propose, AdMob does not work : I got errors like `03-07 15:31:08.179: E/Ads(13242): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenLayout.
`

Answer (score 0):

Set your min SDK version to

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

And set your target to 15, and just use this for Admob

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Can't really see any other way to do it I'm afraid.

Comment: I did this, it's working : however, from eclipse, I'm unable to debug on a 2.2 target directly, hence my problem (it says no device compatible with 3.2 (I used target=13 which is minimum supported))